# Getting Outlook Calender events in ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, outlook-calendar

I am building an application in which i have to show a user's status whether he is available or not based on his outlook calender events.

For example if he has set an event of 1pm to 2pm as lunch break then during this time the user will be shown as away.

How to read user's outlook calender events in ASP.Net?

Also if the user is behind Microsoft Exchange Server then what difference it will make?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Office 365 REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations) (if your users are all on Office 365). Or you can use [Exchange Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx) for any version of Exchange starting with 2007 SP1. I'm not sure what you mean by the user being behind Exchange? If the data is on some other server, you'd need an API specific to that server. If it isn't on a server at all (local Outlook PST data), then you can't access it via a web app.

Comment: by being behind exchange server means the user is an exchange server which you have explained that i will need to use EWS.

What if the user is using Local Outlook Calendar or Google Calendar?

Comment: I think Google has an API for accessing their calendars. Local Outlook calendars aren't really accessible to you in a web app.